# no issue when applied makmigration on "model" but migration command throwing exception "error"

Tags: python, django-models

there is no issue when applied makmigration on "model" but migration command throwing exception "error" ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'null'. 
I got this error when i make change on "emails_for_help" help field
I tried by fake_migration and migrated but no use

model

```
class Setup_user(models.Model):
organization=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False,default="")
email_id=models.EmailField(unique=True)
CEO = 'CEO'
GENERAL_MANAGER = 'GM'
JCHOICES = (
    (CEO, 'CEO'),
    (GENERAL_MANAGER, 'General Manager'),
            )
Designation = models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=JCHOICES)
LEVEL1 = "L1"
LEVEL2 = "L2"
LCHOICES = (
    (LEVEL1,"Level 1"),
    (LEVEL2,"Level 2"),
)
job_level=models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=LCHOICES)
EMAIL_CHOICES = ((str(q.email), str(q.email)) for q in User.objects.all())
emails_for_help = MultiSelectField(choices=EMAIL_CHOICES,default="null",max_length=5000,help_text="select with whom you want to share knowledge")

def __str__(self):
    return self.email_id
```

error:

```
C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject>python manage.py migrate
 Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, pkm_app, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying pkm_app.0015_auto_20180417_1723...Traceback (most recent call 
last):
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in 
execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
 self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
 state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, 
fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in 
_migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, 
fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 122, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, 
project_state)
File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in 
database_forwards
field,
File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 306, in add_field
self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site  - 
packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 178, in _remake_table
self.effective_default(create_field)
File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 224, in effective_default
default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
```

File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 936, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
    File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py", line 767, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
    File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py", line 939, in 
     get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
    File "C:\Users\Ekatech7\PycharmProjects\baseproject\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py", line 947, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'null'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue resolved.
approach i chosen for choices in above model was blunder mistake.
It is resolved by using many to many relation for "emails for help" column and modelform with query set approch.

```
class Set_User_Form(ModelForm):
emails_for_help= forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
class Meta:
    model=Setupuser
    exclude=["email_id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  `CHOICES` don’t have `”null”` as an option. If you want null values to be stored, you have to set `null=True`, which means that when a`modelField` is `blank=True`, the empty value will be stored as null. If you just want your form to not pick an option when it loads, don’t set `default`. The error is looking for this:

```
EMAIL_CHOICES = (
    (“null”, “null”)
    (str(q.email), str(q.email)
    )
```

I think you also have your `for` loop backwards. I believe it should be:

```
for q in User.objects.all():
    (str(q.email), str(q.email)
```